# Tracking app battery consumption

Tags: android, shell, adb

I just started to learn Android application development.

For my learning stage, I am trying to build an application to track the battery consumption for apps.

I know that we can use shh command to check the system activity.

> adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo

Then I will get the CPU time and how many kernel is using by application.

However, I am not really sure how to calculate energy consumption for each app. I believe that I have to use some equation to tracking the battery consumption for each application. However, I am not sure which equation i have to use for this issue.

Does anybody know equation check power consumption for each app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an application, best to just get familiar with using the Android API. Here is some suggested tactics for battery observation and measurement.

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html